# Looking for undefined symbol: _ZN5boost11this_thread6hidden9sleep_forERK8timespec

Tags: undefined, symbols

In my program, libboost_thread-gcc48-mt-d-1_61.so.1.61.0 is linked to build a shared library. But when loading the shared library, an error occurred:
undefined symbol: _ZN5boost11this_thread6hidden9sleep_forERK8timespec

and libboost_thread-gcc48-mt-d-1_61.so.1.61.0 only have the symbol below:

```
nm -D libboost_thread-gcc48-mt-d-1_61.so.1.61.0 | grep timespec
000000000003aa6f T _ZN5boost11this_thread5hiden9sleep_forERK8timespec
```

The name difference is thread6hidden and thread5hiden. What are the possible reasons that the shared library looks for this non-existing symbol?

Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: Use  `nm`  with `-C`  to handle [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Versioning, your libboost is newer

Comment: please give more details about how to check libboost version. My libboost is newer than what?

Comment: If a symbol exported with `nm` reports a lower number 9/10 times it is dealing with linking to old/new shared objects. Perhaps you should research the known compatible versions for the software you are building or if rolling your own ensure you are making use of the latest API documented

Comment: Thanks jas. The issue is resolved after I did make clean and build again. I believed the issue happened because I was using a newer version of libboost, later switched to an older version and built again without running make clean.

Comment: Glad it worked, easy fix but not always easy to figure out